Issue with layout, vertical scrolling on body element and a table with horizontal scrolling & sticky headers
I have overflow-y auto on body and a content which contains a table. There is a div that contains the table and it has overflow-x auto for horizontal scrolling in table view. The table has a thead with position sticky and top 0.
My current issues:

If I add the overflow-x auto to the div table container, then the thead sticky positioning is not working (it won't stick to the table top upon y axis scrolling).
If I change thead to fixed position, it does work but creates another issue, it mess up the width of the thead container because fixed is based to screen viewport and not relative to parent.

Is it possible to have an element with position sticky and allow one of the containers to have overflow-x auto without giving a fixed height?
Codesandbox
The structure is as the following:
<div className="main-container">
  <div className="table-container">
    <table>
    <thead> 
      <tr> 
        <th></th>
      </tr>  
    </thead> 
    <tbody> 
    <tr> 
    <td></td>
    </tr>  
    </tbody> 
    </table>  
  </div>
  <section className="table-footer"/>
</div>

.main-container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-grid;
}

.table-container {
  overflow-x: auto; //this will mess thead sticky positioning.  also tried, overflow-x: clip; - but it doesn't work..
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: auto;
  position: relative;
}

thead {
  top: 194px;
  position: sticky; //If i change to position fixed it will work but will create another issue where thead is not relative to parent and will overflow it's width.
}


You'd want to use class not className. className is React nomenclature. Furthermore, cannot use self-closing tags for <table> or <section>, it must be <table></table> and <section class=""></section> Also your CSS mentions thead but your table has no such element within.

@Wongjn Hi, I'm working with next.js. regarding table It has a regular structure..
`










`
just tried to make it short.

Ah I see. I've put your code into a JSFiddle but it doesn't seem to be reproducing the behavior you describe. Please include Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example that still reproduces your issue.

@Wongjn Thank you, added a code sandbox link containing the issue

Adding overflow-x: auto to .table-container stops the table header stickiness from working because, from the MDN documentation:

The element is positioned according to the normal flow of the document, and then offset relative to its nearest scrolling ancestor and containing block (nearest block-level ancestor)

Thus, when you scroll the document vertically, the .table-container moves with the document. The .table-container is not being scrolled itself, so the table headers do not appear sticky to the document.
A workaround could be to make the .table-container to sole scrolling container of the page, thus allowing it to be scrolled and thus making the table headers exhibit sticky behavior:


.app-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto minmax(0, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 100vh;
  height: 100%;
}

.main-content-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 0;
}

.content-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  flex: 1 1 0%;
  min-height: 0;
}

.sidebar-container {
  position: relative;
  user-select: none;
  width: 50px;
}

.my-sidebar {
  background-color: aqua;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  width: 50px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.my-header {
  height: 64px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  z-index: 50;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.table-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}
.table-container > table {
  position: relative;
  border-collapse: separate;
  table-layout: auto;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  line-height: 1.25rem;
  text-indent: 0;
  border-color: inherit;
  border-spacing: 4px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.579);
}
.table-container > table > thead {
  color: white;
  background-color: grey;
  position: sticky;
  top: 4px;
  z-index: 10;
}


.table-container > table > tbody {
  display: table-row-group;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.table-container > table > tbody > tr {
  height: 250px;
  border-collapse: separate;
  background-color: rgb(188, 188, 188);
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: inherit;
}
<div id="root">
  <div class="app-container">
    <div class="sidebar-container">
      <aside class="my-sidebar">Sidebar</aside>
      ;
    </div>
    <div class="main-content-container">
      <header class="my-header">Header</header>
      <div class="content-container">
        <div class="table-container">
          <table>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <td>date</td>
                <td>domain</td>
                <td>user</td>
                <td>source</td>
                <td>destination</td>
                <td>enforcement</td>
                <td>message</td>
                <td>status</td>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <th>Mon Dec 30 2024 13:13:58 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)</th>
                <th>my-domain</th>
                <th>my-user1</th>
                <th>my-source</th>
                <th>my-destination</th>
                <th>MFA</th>
                <th>message</th>
                <th>my-status</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>Mon Dec 30 2024 13:13:58 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)</th>
                <th>my-domain</th>
                <th>my-user2</th>
                <th>my-source</th>
                <th>my-destination</th>
                <th>MFA</th>
                <th>message</th>
                <th>my-status</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>Mon Dec 30 2024 13:13:58 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)</th>
                <th>my-domain</th>
                <th>my-user3</th>
                <th>my-source</th>
                <th>my-destination</th>
                <th>MFA</th>
                <th>message</th>
                <th>my-status</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>Mon Dec 30 2024 13:13:58 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)</th>
                <th>my-domain</th>
                <th>my-user4</th>
                <th>my-source</th>
                <th>my-destination</th>
                <th>MFA</th>
                <th>message</th>
                <th>my-status</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>Mon Dec 30 2024 13:13:58 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)</th>
                <th>my-domain</th>
                <th>my-user5</th>
                <th>my-source</th>
                <th>my-destination</th>
                <th>MFA</th>
                <th>message</th>
                <th>my-status</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>Mon Dec 30 2024 13:13:58 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)</th>
                <th>my-domain</th>
                <th>my-user6</th>
                <th>my-source</th>
                <th>my-destination</th>
                <th>MFA</th>
                <th>message</th>
                <th>my-status</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>Mon Dec 30 2024 13:13:58 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)</th>
                <th>my-domain</th>
                <th>my-user7</th>
                <th>my-source</th>
                <th>my-destination</th>
                <th>MFA</th>
                <th>message</th>
                <th>my-status</th>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




Thank you for the answer.
It's working because you set a fixed height: grid-template-rows: 100vh and it's not what I'm trying to acheive..
I want the vertical scroll to remain on body element. while horizontal scroll be in table container..
If I set the fixed height then i will have no scrolling on the body element.

I don't believe there is any CSS-only solution to this.
